# Valgrind on clion

Tags: c, makefile, valgrind, clion

I was working on a code that our Uni gave us as a homework. And they tend to be extremely strict about not having memory leak. We used to work on "SSH Secure Client" on a host given by our Uni. But now they decided to shut down the host, so we have no access to Unix. And I need to run Valgrind in order to check memory leak.
I tried to search on google of how to run valgrind on Clion in windows 10 but found no solutions. any help?

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/valgrind4win/wiki/DevelopmentEnvironment/

Comment: how to use clion instead of eclipse ?

Comment: Valgrind runs in a Windows Subsystem for Linux environment, and I'm pretty sure also on Mac.  If you have *any* common computing environment under your personal control then you ought to be able to set up a development environment in which you can run Valgrind.